# How is an array declared/initialized by default in java?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, access-modifiers

I wanted to ask that what is the default access specifiers/modifiers for an array in java? 
For example if I write

```
int arr[];
```

What will it be by default?
Is it `public abstract final` or `public` by default?

I am asking this question because I am unable to understand comment made by Tom Ball.

> I found why default serialVersionUIDs for arrays were different. That calculation includes the class's modifiers, and it turns out all arrays are "public abstract final", not "public" (a new "gotcha" Java interview question :-). Changing that in the runtime, and now all arrays have the same UIDs, even different object classes.

Here is the link https://groups.google.com/d/msg/j2objc-discuss/1zCZYvxBGhY/ZpIRKPLFBgAJ

Can Someone explain?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: The same as other variables. Arrays have no special behaviour.

Comment: It's not `public`, nor `public abstract final`. It's package private.

Comment: It's not `public` because no modifier means "package private". It's not final because you're not declaring it final. It's not abstract because you're not declaring a class.

Comment: Hi folks.
Sorry to have posted without complete info. The question is not duplicate. It's complete now. Could you please explain instead of down-voting the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a declaration like

```
int arr[];
```

you are declaring a *variable*. This variable has exactly those access modifiers, you are declaring. If you don’t specify any modifiers on a class variable, it will be package-private by default. Note that variables can *never* be `abstract`.

The reason why you don’t understand the cited text is, that you are confusing the *class* modifiers of the variable’s type with the *variable*’s modifiers.

Letting arrays aside, if you declare a variable like `Foo bar`, then the class `Foo` has modifiers independently of the modifiers of the variable `bar`.

Now, the same applies for array types. In Java, arrays are objects, hence have a class type. At runtime, you may invoke `getClass()` on an array just like on any other object and you will get a `Class` object representing a synthetic class. You can also access an array class via class literal:

```
Class<?> clazz=int[].class; // int[]
int mod=clazz.getModifiers();
if(Modifier.isPublic(mod)) System.out.print("public ");
if(Modifier.isAbstract(mod)) System.out.print("abstract ");
if(Modifier.isFinal(mod)) System.out.print("final ");
System.out.print(clazz);
System.out.print(" implements");
for(Class<?> cl:clazz.getInterfaces())
  System.out.print(" "+cl.getName());
System.out.println();
```

It will print

```
public abstract final class [I implements java.lang.Cloneable java.io.Serializable
```

showing that the class representing the array type `int[]` has the special name `[I` and the modifiers `abstract` and `final`, a combination that is impossible for ordinary classes.

Note that an array class is `public`, if either it’s an array of primitive values or its element type is `public` as well. As explained, this doesn’t stop you from declaring non-`public` variables of such a type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Holger. A great explanation!!!!! Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

The post that you linked refers to the access modifiers of the (dynamically created, synthetic) class object that represents the array: `int[].class` in your case.

There is no relation between the modifiers of a class and the modifiers of a field.

Think of it like this: the class `java.lang.String` is `public`, but you are free to make a `private` field of type String.